# How to draw the mouse cursor on the taken screenshot?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program for fun, which takes a screenshot. But I couldn't find how to draw the mouse cursor on the taken screenshot.

How to deal with this, please?

~IDE: Visual Studio 2013.
~OS: Windows 7 SP1.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to obtain the cursor information using [GetCursorInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
CURSORINFO cinfo;
ZeroMemory(&cinfo, sizeof(CURSORINFO));
cinfo.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
GetCursorInfo(&cinfo);
```

Then you can draw it into your screenshot bitmap using [DrawIconEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
DrawIconEx(hdcMemory, cinfo.ptScreenPos.x, cinfo.ptScreenPos.y, cinfo.hCursor, 0, 0, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
```